# React + Redux - wait for action to end?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I'm using [React Dropzone](https://react-dropzone.js.org) (but I have the same issue in many different places). This is a function in my main component:

```
onDrop(images) {
  this.props.dispatch(setImages(images));

   this.props.images.forEach(file => {
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = () => // render images
    reader.onerror = () => // display error
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
  });
}
```

The dispatch just pushes array of images to the state and then I map it to props.

Unfortunately dispatch takes some time and `this.props.images` is `undefined` in the example above, it works well if I put in a timeout of 2 seconds or so, but it's way too dangerous.

How can I fix that? I've tried promises but I don't know who they work and I feel like they're mostly for async requests?

Comment: I've tried but it never worked - I'm dispatching actions from my components and all examples I could find were using external object creators which I feel I don't need as they're make my project way too complex.

Comment: setImages is `sync`, I'm just moving files to Redux store so I can use them elsewhere (no worries, they're really small).

Comment: @Li357 Redux's `dispatch` would not synchronously update `this.props`. `this.props` would take on a new value the next time the component is rendered and that is when the `images` would be there.

Comment: OP, can you show us what your `setImages` and the `//render images` code does?

Comment: And the redux connect too

Comment: Is it not possible to read the files in `componentWillReceiveProps()`? It's the React way and is much more manageable than using promise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FileReader is asynchronous, and not the best choice for previewing files with base64. Base64 will take up more memory and takes longer to decode/encode back and forth. Best is to create a [object url](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL) instead.

If you are building a single page application and never reload the page then you should also take care of [revoking](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/revokeObjectURL) it when you don't need it anymore.

you can get away with 1 of 2 asynchronous task (the other being `image.onload`)

```
window.URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL

// Nameing convention: you are passing in files
// to the function not images, so name it 'files'

onDrop(files) {
  this.props.dispatch(setImages(files))

  this.props.files.forEach(file => {
    const url = URL.createObjectURL(file)
    // render images
  })
}
```